# c++ assigning Object values from another object fail

Tags: c++, arrays, object, assign

I'm having some major issues with my code at the moment and I hope someone can shed some light on it.

In my code I have made; players = new Player*[2]; along with players[i] = new Player(); in a for-loop. And given them real values.

Later on in my code, I then want to do this:

```
players[0] = players[1];
delete players[1];
```

While debugging. players[0] gets the values of players[1]. But the very next line players[0] gets; string name = < Bad Ptr > and along with some int values that becomes -17912312.

My first thought was that I needed to create a operator= så in Player. I created:

`Player& operator=(const Player& right);`

```
Player& Player::operator=(const Player& right)
{
this->name=right.name;
this->coins=right.coins;
this->bet=right.bet;
return *this;
}
```

This had no effect. It didnt even go into the function. Why can't I assign the values?

Comment: You can't overload `operator=` for pointers. Why not just use objects instead of pointers and get rid of the overloaded operator, which basically does the same thing as the default.

Comment: Could you type that in code?

Comment: Instead of using pointers and `new`, just use `Player players[2];`. No memory leaks, nicer syntax, no heap allocations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the shown code `players[0] = players[1];` will leak the object originally pointed by `players[0]`. And in the next statement you nuke the object behind one pointer you now have in both slots. If you don't set it to NULL immediately, you're holding dangling pointers that are not usable for anything.

Writing op= is completely irrelevant for the case, and you should not do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dangling pointer issue. When you make the assignment

```
players[0] = players[1];
```

And immediately after delete players[1], you are in effect making both memory locations inaccessible. Could you explain your aim a little better? Like has been said, you cannot do an operator= overload for pointers. Why do you need to remove players[1] in the first place? Will edit with updated advice when you clarify!

Comment: I'm making a small game. When one of the players lost the game, I wanted to remove them completely.